# How to configure SSL certificate into PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: ssl, jboss, centos7, postgresql-9.4, adempiere

I'm using Adempiere 360 ERP solution with Java language, Database PostgreSQL 9.4 and iReport (For reporting) and using CentOS 7 Server. Recently Vendor provide me 4 files about ssl configuration.
But i fail to configure ssl into PostgreSQL 9.4.
I follow some instruction from google but finally fail.
Need proper direction.

Answer (score 1):

What steps are you following?

You have to copy your signed certificate and private key to the required locations on the database server.

Then you just have to edit *postgresql.conf*

```
ssl=on
```

In the *pg_hba.conf* change the host option to hostssl

```
hostssl mydb mydbuser 192.168.122.0/24 md5
```

Then restart your server.

[Read this tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/5.8/html/installation_guide/sect-Red_Hat_Satellite-Installation_Guide-Configuration-Configuring_the_Database_to_use_SSL#proc-Red_Hat_Satellite-Installation_Guide-Configuring_the_Database_to_use_SSL-Configuring_SSL_on_the_database_server)